# C++20 Deducing the dimensions of a multidimensional array into a parameter pack

Tags: c++, arrays, variadic-templates, c++20

I am implementing a container in the form of a multidimensional array. I am trying to replicate [std::to_array (C++ 20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array), a function that creates a `std::array` from a one dimensional built-in array, using my multidimensional array:

```c++
template<typename T, std::size_t... N>
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N...> to_mdarray(T (&a)[N]));

int arr[5][12]{};
to_mdarray(arr); // Returns mdarray<int, 5, 12>
```

I would like to deduce the dimensions of the built-in array into `N` and return the corresponding `mdarray`. I have not managed to figure out the correct syntax, I've always ended up with errors. Either I am not unfolding the pack properly, or the compiler thinks I am trying to declare a function pointer or lambda. I haven't found any resources online either.

I found two alternatives so far. One is to decay the array into a pointer and let the user specify the dimensions.

```c++
template<typename T, std::size_t... N>
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N...> to_mdarray(T* const a);

int arr[5][12]{};
to_mdarray<5, 12>(arr);
```

I found the other in [blog from Stanislav Arnaudov](https://palikar.github.io/posts/array_dim_deduction/). It involves generating N-th dimensional overloads using recursive macros:

```c++
#define SIZE_T_S_1 size_t N
#define SIZE_T_S_2 SIZE_T_S_1 , size_t M
#define SIZE_T_S_3 SIZE_T_S_2 , size_t L

#define BRACKETS_S_1 [N]
#define BRACKETS_S_2 BRACKETS_S_1[M]
#define BRACKETS_S_3 BRACKETS_S_2[L]

#define LETTERS_S_1 N
#define LETTERS_S_2 LETTERS_S_1, M
#define LETTERS_S_3 LETTERS_S_2, L

#define TO_MD_N(dim) template<typename T, SIZE_T_S_##dim>                                       \
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, LETTERS_S_##dim> to_mdarray(T (&values) BRACKETS_S_##dim);

TO_MD_N(1);
TO_MD_N(2);
TO_MD_N(3);

// Equivalent to:
// TO_MD_N(1)
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N> to_mdarray(T (&values)[N]);

// TO_MD_N(2)
template<typename T, std::size_t, std::size_t M>
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N, M> to_mdarray(T (&values)[N][M]);

// TO_MD_N(3)
template<typename T, std::size_t, std::size_t M, std::size_t L>
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N, M, L> to_mdarray(T (&values)[N][M][L]);
```

Both of these solutions have flaws. One requires the user to enter the correct dimensions, the other requires defining the same function multiple times and restricting the number of dimensions.

Is there any way to do this in C++20 or is it impossible at the moment?

Comment: [`std::rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) and [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately my usual trend of Boost.Mp11 one-liners will come to an end here, since Boost.Mp11 doesn't really deal with *values* very well and we need to convert `int[5][12]` into `mdarray<int, 5, 12>` and there's no easy mechanism to do that with that library.

Instead we just do it by hand. [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) gives you the `N`th extent and [`std::rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) gives you the number of extents. Combine that with `make_index_sequence` and you can get all of 'em:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename>
struct mdarray_for_impl;

template <typename A, size_t... Is>
struct mdarray_for_impl<A, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    using type = mdarray<std::remove_all_extents_t<A>, std::extent_v<A, Is>...>;
};

template <typename T>
using mdarray_for = mdarray_for_impl<T, std::make_index_sequence<std::rank_v<T>>>::type;
```

Here `mdarray_for<int[1][2][3]>` will yield the type `mdarray<int, 1, 2, 3>`.

---

A [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) version anyway requires a couple helper aliases

```cpp
// a type-only mdarray
template <typename T, typename... Ns>
using mdarray_t = mdarray<T, Ns::value...>;

// a type-only extent
template <typename T, typename V>
using mp_extent = mp_size_t<std::extent_v<T, V::value>>;
```

which then allows:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using mdarray_for2 = 
    mp_apply<mdarray_t,
    mp_append<
        mp_list<std::remove_all_extents_t<T>>,
        mp_transform_q<
            mp_bind<mp_extent, T, _1>,
            mp_iota_c<std::rank_v<T>>>
        >>;
```

This is the same algorithm as before, except `mp_iota_c<std::rank_v<T>>` to get the sequence of extent indices (instead of `std::make_index_sequence`) and then `mp_transform_q` to get the nth extent (instead of using it directly in a pack expansion).

In this case for `int[5][12]` we build up `mp_list<int, mp_size_t<5>, mp_size_t<12>>` (because we're all types, no values) and then `mp_apply` turns that into `mdarray_t<...>` which turns it into `mdarray<int, 5, 12>`.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to deduce the dimensions of the built-in array into N and return the corresponding mdarray.

Maybe... with a little of recursion...

```
template <std::size_t ... Ns, typename T>
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, Ns...> get_mdarray_t (T const &)
 { return {}; }

template <std::size_t ... Ns, typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_mdarray_t (T const (&arr)[N])
 { return get_mdarray_t<Ns..., N>(arr[0]); }
```

you can construct a `using` that can be useful

```
template <typename T>
using mdarray_t = decltype(get_mdarray_t<>(std::declval<T>()));
```

The following is a full compiling C++11 example

```
#include <utility>

template <typename, std::size_t...>
struct mdarray
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Ns, typename T>
constexpr mdarray<std::remove_cv_t<T>, Ns...> get_mdarray_t (T const &)
 { return {}; }

template <std::size_t ... Ns, typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_mdarray_t (T const (&arr)[N])
 { return get_mdarray_t<Ns..., N>(arr[0]); }

template <typename T>
using mdarray_t = decltype(get_mdarray_t<>(std::declval<T>()));

int main ()
 {
   using A0 = int;
   using A1 = int[2u];
   using A2 = int[2u][3u];
   using A3 = int[2u][3u][5u];

   using T0 = mdarray_t<A0>;
   using T1 = mdarray_t<A1>;
   using T2 = mdarray_t<A2>;
   using T3 = mdarray_t<A3>;

   using U0 = mdarray<int> ;
   using U1 = mdarray<int, 2u>;
   using U2 = mdarray<int, 2u, 3u>;
   using U3 = mdarray<int, 2u, 3u, 5u>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<T0, U0>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<T1, U1>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<T2, U2>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<T3, U3>::value, "!" );
 }
```